# Angular 2 RC.5 Plunker error: TypeError: core_1.NgModule is not a function

Tags: angular, plunker

I upgraded my Angular 2 Plunker from RC.4 to RC.5 by doing the following:

- updated systemjs.config.js to match the [quickstart plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html)
- updated main.ts to match the quickstart plunker
- created file app/app.module.ts, and populated it with what the quickstart plunker has

I don't see any other changes that are required for my simply plunker.

I keep getting this error: `Error: TypeError: core_1.NgModule is not a function(…)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit the exact same problem on my project. It worked on 1 pc, didn't work on another.
Turns out the solution was simple:

**Clear your browser cache**

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure what the problem is, this fixes it:

- save your changes
- reload the page/plunker

The error no longer appears.  (I assume it has something to do with some old files that are not getting regenerated properly.)

Comment: not on pluker but happened to me when I was using bundled-angular-dependencies(RC4) which I forgot to update. Probably cache caused it to plunker

Comment: I am getting the same error. Are you following the tour of heroes tutorial? If yes I think has been changed recently. I have opened this issue right now: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/issues/71

Answer (score 0):

The tour of heroes tutorial has changed and introduced app.module.ts and also versions in systemjs.config.js for ex: ngVer is now @2.0.0-rc.5'. Replace the systemjs.config.js and everything worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the angular upgrade rc4 to rc5 docs here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html