# angular2 rc5 + plunker : XHR error (404) loading https://npmcdn.com/@angular/src/forms when using ngModel

Tags: angular, plunker

for using `ngModel` directive, I included

- import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
- @NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule
    ],
  ...
  })

as mentioned [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel). But now I'm getting xhr error for loading @angular/forms from `npmcdn` (guess it won't be there) while using [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qL4Mc5NeLB7BZZxt7IDa?p=preview). any idea on what to include in plunker ?

Comment: update working plunk in the question. related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887044/angular-2-rc-5-plunker-error-typeerror-core-1-ngmodule-is-not-a-function .

Answer (score 0):

Add to `app.component.ts`:

```
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms'
```

and

```
providers: [NgModel],
```

to the `@Component({...})`

Comment: we need not import `NgModel` as we are importing `FormsModule` in root component. same goes for `providers`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have 'forms' specified in ngPackageNames in config file

```
    var ngPackageNames = [
  'common',
  'compiler',
  'core',
  'forms',
  'http',
  'platform-browser',
  'platform-browser-dynamic',
  'router',
  'router-deprecated',
  'upgrade',
];
```

Comment: can you look at the plunker i shared in question. it didn't help